# Integrate 2 eclipse projects using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, repository

I have a web project in my repository and recently I've received another project, just code, that I need to use as a submodule on the first one (just java entity classes). Something like:

```
./web-project/.project
./entities/.project
```

As I believe it's going to be changed often I'd need it to still be a separate eclipse project. What I want is to use the `entities` in the `web-project`, like I'd have included the `.jar` as a dependency.

Apart from creating my own maven repo and getting the jars from there, Is there way to add it to my build path given I'm using maven to build both projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it installing the built artifact to the local `m2` repo before building the `web-app`. It works both on eclipse and running the builds from command line.

On the dependent project `entities` add the following plugin to the `install` build step:

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-install-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-file</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <packaging>jar</packaging>
                    <file>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</file>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

And declare the dependency as usual in the `web-project` POM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question. It sounds like you want to have the dependent project be included in the Eclipse build path when generating the Eclipse project from maven. Is that right?

If so, the only way I know to do this is to run mvn eclipse:eclipse from a parent maven project. That is, you would need to create a pom.xml is some directory, and then put both of your existing projects underneath that. Something like:

```
./parent-folder
  /pom.xml
  /web-project
    /pom.xml
  /entities
    /pom.xml
```

Then, of course, declare the appropriate maven dependencies within the pom.xml files.

Comment: It's not exactly that. I only want to be able to use classes from `entities` in `web-project`, like if I had included the generated `entities` jar as a dependency. I can't really change the folder structure to make a project that includes both.

Comment: You just want the jar file on the build path? Then just a simple maven dependency should work. The parent folder is needed if you want the actual eclipse project dependency to be set automatically.  Of course, you could just set the build path manually....Or am I still not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything you need to do other than just declaring `entities` as as a `<dependency>` of the `web-project` Maven project.

This relationship ensures that `entities` eclipse project source is automatically included in `web-project`'s buildpath as long as you have:

- both projects imported into eclipse and marked as `Maven` projects using the `m2e` plugin
- the `Maven > Enable Workspace Resolution` option enabled

As for building them together, you can just create a throw-away parent project (if you don't want to keep the parent project) listing these two projects as `module`s. Otherwise, you have to build the `entities` project and install it to your local repo before building the `web-project`. However you will see the changes to the `entity` class readily available on the `web-project` project since you have the former's source in its buildpath.